# How to get the bazel dependencies of Tensorflow by bazel query?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I just start reading code of Tensorflow. I have some experience with other frameworks.

In order to see the dependencies of the whole Tensorflow project, I would like to use `bazel query` to print the dependency graph.

The bazel tutorial provides a simple [example](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cpp.html#review-the-dependency-graph).

But when I did

```
bazel query --nohost_deps --noimplicit_deps 'deps(//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package)' --output graph
```

I got errors :

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/BUILD:698:1: no such package '@androidndk//': The repository could not be resolved and referenced by '//tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal:cpu_check'
ERROR: Evaluation of query "deps(//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package)" failed: errors were encountered while computing transitive closure
Loading: 246 packages loaded
```

Since the project is large, I hope that I can see the dependencies between each folder, each file so that I can add some features by my self.

The bazel is different from CMake and GNU make tools, so I have trouble transfering to this tool.

What is a good way to see the big picture of Tensorflow project(a colossus)?

```
tensorflow$ find . -name "BUILD"
./tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/example/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/quantization/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/rnn/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/all_reduce/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/stateless/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/gdr/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/kernel_methods/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/recurrent/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/periodic_resample/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/verbs/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/predictor/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/feature_column/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/custom_plugin_examples/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/cloud/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/cloud/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/receptive_field/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/constrained_optimization/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/compiler/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/solvers/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/keras/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/boosted_trees/proto/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/boosted_trees/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/boosted_trees/estimator_batch/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/boosted_trees/lib/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/boosted_trees/resources/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/cluster_resolver/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/remote_fused_graph/pylib/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/rpc/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/rpc/python/kernel_tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/rpc/python/ops/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/meta_graph_transform/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/proto/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/hybrid/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/kernels/v4/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/optimizer_v2/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/data/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/data/python/kernel_tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/bayesflow/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/coder/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/estimator/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/grid_rnn/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/libsvm/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/mpi/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/proto/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/proto/python/kernel_tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/proto/python/ops/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/metrics/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/timeseries/examples/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/timeseries/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/timeseries/python/timeseries/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/timeseries/python/timeseries/state_space_models/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/hvx/clock_cycle_profiling/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/hvx/hvx_ops_support_checker/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/memory_stats/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/reduce_slice_ops/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/slim/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tfprof/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/graph_editor/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/android/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/integrate/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/linear_optimizer/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tpu/profiler/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tpu/profiler/pip_package/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/saved_model/cc/saved_model/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/saved_model/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/model_pruning/examples/cifar10/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/model_pruning/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/nearest_neighbor/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/resampler/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/summary/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/staging/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/nn/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/tensorboard/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/signal/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/image/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/util/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/text/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/decision_trees/proto/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/layers/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/layers/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/rnn_colorbot/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/densenet/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/revnet/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/resnet50/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/spinn/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/linear_regression/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/rnn_ptb/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/gan/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/l2hmc/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/sparsemax/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/rate/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/lookup/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/distributions/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/autograph/examples/benchmarks/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/autograph/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/distribute/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/examples/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/specs/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/quantize/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/training/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/fused_conv/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/checkpoint/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/bigtable/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/stat_summarizer/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/opt/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/mixed_precision/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/mixed_precision/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/losses/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/ignite/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/kafka/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/hadoop/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/factorization/examples/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/factorization/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/factorization/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/labeled_tensor/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/deprecated/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/input_pipeline/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/input_pipeline/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/gan/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/kinesis/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/mpi_collectives/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/framework/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/crf/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/batching/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/testing/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/hooks/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/ffmpeg/default/BUILD
./tensorflow/contrib/ffmpeg/BUILD
./tensorflow/cc/BUILD
./tensorflow/cc/saved_model/BUILD
./tensorflow/cc/saved_model/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/cc/tools/BUILD
./tensorflow/cc/profiler/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xrt/cc/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xrt/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xrt/tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xrt/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/rpc/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/experimental/xla_sharding/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/llvm_ir/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/interpreter/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/llvm_gpu_backend/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/client/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/client/lib/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/tools/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/python_api/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/plugin/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/jit/graphcycles/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/jit/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/jit/ops/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/jit/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/aot/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/cc/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/ops/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/lib/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/BUILD
./tensorflow/compiler/tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/debug/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/data/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/platform/s3/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/platform/default/gpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/verifiers/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/inputs/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/data/vectorization/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/data/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/utils/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/costs/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/grappler/graph_analyzer/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/tpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/eager/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/ops/compat/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/api_def/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/summary/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/nccl/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/protobuf/tpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/util/rpc/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/util/proto/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/util/ctc/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_bundle/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/cpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/runtime/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/advisor/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/profiler/rpc/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/profiler/rpc/client/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/profiler/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/lib/db/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/boosted_trees/quantiles/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/boosted_trees/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/hexagon/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/tensor_forest/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/data/experimental/sql/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/data/experimental/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/data/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/batching_util/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/fuzzing/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/lookup_tables/BUILD
./tensorflow/core/kernels/neon/BUILD
./tensorflow/stream_executor/host/BUILD
./tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/BUILD
./tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/BUILD
./tensorflow/stream_executor/BUILD
./tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/BUILD
./tensorflow/stream_executor/lib/BUILD
./tensorflow/stream_executor/rocm/BUILD
./tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/js/BUILD
./tensorflow/c/BUILD
./tensorflow/c/eager/BUILD
./tensorflow/c/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/multibox_detector/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/wav_to_spectrogram/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/get_started/regression/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/android/assets/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/android/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/label_image/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/saved_model/integration_tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/adding_an_op/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/learn/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/BUILD
./tensorflow/examples/tf2_showcase/BUILD
./tensorflow/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/toco/tensorflow_graph_matching/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/toco/tflite/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/toco/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/toco/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/core/api/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/models/smartreply/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/models/smartreply/demo/app/src/main/assets/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/models/smartreply/demo/app/src/main/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/models/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/nnapi/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/c/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/examples/lstm/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/writer/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/microfrontend/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/microfrontend/lib/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/micro_speech/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/micro_speech/micro_features/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/testing/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/experimental/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/profiling/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/c/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/examples/android/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/examples/android/app/src/main/assets/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/examples/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/delegates/nnapi/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/delegates/flex/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tools/evaluation/proto/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tools/evaluation/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tools/accuracy/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tools/accuracy/ilsvrc/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tools/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tools/optimize/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tools/optimize/calibration/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark/android/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/schema/builtin_ops_header/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/schema/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/jni/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/ovic/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/ovic/src/testdata/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/ovic/demo/app/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/src/testhelper/java/org/tensorflow/lite/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/src/test/native/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/assets/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/tutorials/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/python/testdata/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/python/optimize/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/lib_package/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/testing/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/testing/model_coverage/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/testing/kernel_test/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/BUILD
./tensorflow/lite/kernels/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/proto_text/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/def_file_filter/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/docker/notebooks/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/docker/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/ci_build/gpu_build/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/ci_build/remote/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/build_info/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/test/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/common/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/api/golden/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/api/lib/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/api/tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/docs/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/optimization/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/mlpbtxt/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/compatibility/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/compatibility/update/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/benchmark/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD
./tensorflow/tools/lib_package/BUILD
./tensorflow/java/BUILD
./tensorflow/java/src/main/native/BUILD
./tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/compat/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/feature_column/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/compiler/tensorrt/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/compiler/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/keras/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/keras/api/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/keras/mixed_precision/experimental/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/linalg/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/boosted_trees/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/testdata/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/signal/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/distributions/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/random/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/debug/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/benchmarks/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/kernel_tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/experimental/benchmarks/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/experimental/kernel_tests/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/experimental/kernel_tests/optimization/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/experimental/kernel_tests/serialization/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/experimental/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/ops/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/data/util/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/estimator/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/module/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/tpu/experimental/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/tpu/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/tpu/profiler/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/saved_model/model_utils/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/saved_model/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/ops/linalg/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/ops/parallel_for/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/ops/signal/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/ops/ragged/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/ops/losses/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/eager/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/static_analysis/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/common_transformers/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/testing/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/core/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/converters/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/utils/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/autograph/lang/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/distribute/experimental/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/distribute/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/tools/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/training/saving/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/training/tracking/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/profiler/internal/BUILD
./tensorflow/python/profiler/BUILD
./tensorflow/go/BUILD
./third_party/python_runtime/BUILD
./third_party/icu/BUILD
./third_party/jpeg/BUILD
./third_party/tensorrt/BUILD
./third_party/fft2d/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/clang6/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/remote/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/cpus/arm/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/cpus/py/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/cpus/py3/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/generate/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu16.04/clang/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu16.04/py3/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu14.04/cuda10.0-cudnn7/cuda/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu14.04/gcc-nvcc/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu14.04/gcc-nvcc-cuda9.0/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu14.04/gcc-nvcc-cuda10.0/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu14.04/cuda9.0-cudnn7/cuda/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu14.04/py3/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu14.04/tensorrt5/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/ubuntu14.04/gcc7-nvcc-cuda10.0/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/win_1803/py36/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/win_1803/bazel_018/BUILD
./third_party/toolchains/preconfig/win_1803/BUILD
./third_party/nasm/BUILD
./third_party/ngraph/BUILD
./third_party/keras_applications_archive/BUILD
./third_party/flatbuffers/BUILD
./third_party/py/numpy/BUILD
./third_party/py/BUILD
./third_party/mpi/BUILD
./third_party/systemlibs/BUILD
./third_party/eigen3/BUILD
./third_party/boringssl/BUILD
./third_party/android/BUILD
./third_party/sycl/crosstool/BUILD
./third_party/sycl/sycl/BUILD
./third_party/sycl/BUILD
./third_party/examples/eager/spinn/BUILD
./third_party/hwloc/BUILD
./third_party/BUILD
./third_party/clang_toolchain/BUILD
./third_party/nccl/BUILD
./third_party/protobuf/BUILD
./third_party/highwayhash/BUILD
./third_party/mkl/BUILD
./third_party/git/BUILD
./third_party/llvm/BUILD
./third_party/grpc/BUILD
./third_party/pasta/BUILD
./third_party/ortools/BUILD
./third_party/aws/BUILD
./third_party/kafka/BUILD
./third_party/hadoop/BUILD
./third_party/mkl_dnn/BUILD
./third_party/mpi_collectives/BUILD
./third_party/kissfft/BUILD
./third_party/gpus/crosstool/BUILD
./third_party/gpus/BUILD
./third_party/gpus/cuda/BUILD
./third_party/gpus/rocm/BUILD
./BUILD
```

Answer (score 1):

If just want to see the build target dependency graph, you can try to add **--keep_going** parameter to your bazel query command.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is:

```
ERROR: tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/BUILD:698:1: no such package '@androidndk//': The repository could not be resolved and referenced by '//tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal:cpu_check'
```

Have you ran the configure script and installed the Android NDK? If you have, is the `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` environment variable set to the path to the Android NDK?

Comment: I run the configure and the setting of android is the last one of configuration questions: `Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds? [y/N]: Not configuring the WORKSPACE for Android builds.` I leave it to default.

Comment: It looks like the query command is reaching into parts of the Tensorflow project that needs the Android NDK. Perhaps you need to say `y` to configure the WORKSPACE for Android builds.